# Counting the sum of the digits

Tags: combinatorics

The problem is,

> Let $S$ be the set of five-digit numbers formed by the digits $1, 2,
> 3, 4$ and $5$, using each digit exactly once such that exactly two odd
>   positions are occupied by odd digits. What is the sum of the digits in
>   the rightmost position of the numbers in S?

I am looking for some approach for solving this problem.

Comment: Suppose $X_1X_2X_3X_4X_5$ is the 5-digit number. Then if we pick the number at random from $S$, then $X_1X_3X_5$ is uniformly distributed in $132, 134, 352, 354, 512, 514$ and all their permutations (e.g.: $132, 123, 213, 231, 312, 321$, and so on). Then, $E[X_1+X_3+X_5] = \frac{1}{6}(6+8+10+12+8+10) = 9$. Finally, note that the distributions of $X_1$, $X_3$, and $X_5$ are identical; so $E[X_5]=3$. Hence, the required answer is $3|S|$.

Answer (score 2):

If the last digit is even,

2 odd numbers out of 3 can be arranged in 3P2=3! ways,the two even numbers can be arranged in 2! ways

There sum = $$(3! * 2) * (2+4) = 72$$

If the last digit is odd, i.e either 1,3,5

an odd number can only occupy an odd position, so 2C1 = 2
Either one of the two odd digits of the 5 digit number can be selected in 2C1 = 2
Now, the other remaining odd number will have only 2 places left.

The even numbers can be arranged in $$2!$$ ways.

So $$(2 * 2 * 2 * 2) * (1 + 3 + 5) = 144$$

Total sum of right most digits =$$72 + 144 = 216$$

Answer (score 1):

A more probabilistic version of the idea used below, indeed essentially a full solution, was given in a comment by @Srivatsan Narayanan.

Conveniently, the odd digits have mean $3$, and so do the even digits.
So we only need to count the number of allowed permutations, and multiply by $3$.  It is somewhat easier, or at least safer,  to count the complement.

There are $(3!)(2)$, that is, $12$ permutations with *all* the odd digits in odd positions.

Next we count the permutations with exactly *one* odd digit in an odd position. That *digit* can be chosen in $3$ ways. For each choice, its *position* can be chosen in $3$ ways. Once we have done that, the remaining odd digits can be placed in $2$ ways, and then the even digits can be placed in $2$ ways, for a total of $(3)(3)(2)(2)$, that is, $36$.

So there are $48$ forbidden permutations, leaving $5!-48=72$ allowed permutations.

The required total is therefore $(3)(72)$, which is $216$.